# How can I reduce the salt taste in a dish

Tags: salt

Can a dish prepared with too much salt be overcome without changing the water or ingredient content? Or least in a drastic way.

Comment: You should also specify what kind of dish. A soup may be mitigated adding cream, but a steak will be more difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

a stew or soup can be fixed by adding a halved potato into it and simmering for as long as it takes for the potato to cook. Carefully remove the potato with a slotted spoon afterwards.

Comment: This works very well in a lot of different dishes. Anything that is fluid enough to cook the potato.